# How to change the column width of a Individual column in excel in excel through Apache-POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to change the column width of a column I have seen many answers suggesting the use of  "AutoSizeColumn(int)" but the problem with that is that all columns have different sizes and it creates kind of a mess so i want to set all columns ( except one ) to one single width how do i do this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a default column width that controls all columns in the sheet that don't have their own custom width set.  Use the [`setDefaultColumnWidth` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setDefaultColumnWidth-int-).

> Set the default column width for the sheet (if the columns do not define their own width) in characters

```
sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(numChars);
```

Individual columns can override this default with the [`setColumnWidth` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setColumnWidth-int-int-).  The width here is in 1/256ths of a character, different from the default width units.

> Set the width (in units of 1/256th of a character width)

Comment: After opening the excel file it shows that the file contains some unreadable content. This started happening after i used this code. Also I have merged cells in columns if that matters.